# Taking picture with existing camera-app programmatically not using preview-capture-button

Tags: java, android, camera

Is it possible to take a picture programmatically with the standard camera-app not using preivew-capture-button or do I need to create my own camera?

I know how to start the existing camera-app with an Intent, but I don't want to use the standard capture-button in the preview.

After the existing camera-app is started I need to do something like invoking a "takePicture"-method from another activity.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this even possible?

No, there is nothing in the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` protocol for this.